# How to know offcanvas bootstrap 5 is show or not?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to know how can I realize offcanvas is show or not with javascript?

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvas" aria-labelledby="offcanvasLabel">
<div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
<div class="offcanvas-body">
    Content for the offcanvas goes here. You can place just about any Bootstrap component or custom elements here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Event**
Bootstrap's offcanvas class exposes a few events for hooking into offcanvas functionality.

**hidden.bs.offcanvas**
: this event fires immediately when the **hide** method has been called.

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', 
function () {
    console.log('hidden')
})
```

**show.bs.offcanvas**
: this fires immediately when the **show** intance method has been called.

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
myOffcanvas.addEventListener('show.bs.offcanvas', 
function () {
    console.log('show')
})
```

You can read it here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

It is at the bottom of BS5 offcanvas docs:

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas')
myOffcanvas.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function () {
  // do something...
})
```

Just replace hidden. with show. / shown. depending on when you want to trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Visible offcanvas has "show" class, so you can test for visibility with `offcanvasEl.classList.contains("show")`. Beware that during offcanvas hiding `'show'` class is still there, so another test I suggest would be `!offcanvasEl.classList.contains("hiding")`. All together,

```
if ( offcanvasEl.classList.contains("show") && !offcanvasEl.classList.contains("hiding") ) {
  const offCanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(offcanvasEl);
  offCanvas.hide(); // or something else you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for "show" class will not work if Offcanvas is used in a responsive layout.I nmy view there are two alternatives:

1. Tracking the status via event listeners; or
2. Check visibility with window.getComputedStyle(offcanvas)

Answer (score -1):

As explained [in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/offcanvas/#options)..

```
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvas')
var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
bsOffcanvas.show()
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/7t1gXLbPp1)

---

Related: [How to open Bootstrap v5 Offcanvas using switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788820/how-to-open-bootstrap-v5-offcanvas-using-switches/66800905#66800905)

Comment: OP is asking how to know if it is open or not.